# C# DllExport -Can't use AForge functions

Tags: c#, delphi, dllexport

I am trying to export code from a function in C# to Delphi. I used DllExport with stdcall convention and made some tests :it works. I tested for integers and strings as params. The problem occurs when I try to use a class from Aforge library in C#. Delphi returns an error: "External Exception E0434F4D".

```
public class ProcessClass
{
    [DllExport(CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static void ProcessImage()
    {
        try
        {
            Erosion erosion = new Erosion();
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Delphi code:

```
procedure ProcessImage; stdcall; external 'C:\Users\Reznicencu Bogdan\source\repos\OCR\OCR\bin\x86\Release\OCR.dll';

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ProcessImage;
end;
```

The error apears at Erosion.Actually every function I use from Aforge library generates an error. I used Try/catch because I know Delphi can't catch exceptions from unmanaged code but it still doesn't work.
 How can I solve this error?

The event log says: First chance exception at $767EDDC2. Exception class EExternalException with message 'External exception E0434F4D'. Process Project1.exe (9528)

Comment: and what does the exception say?

Comment: Hard to say. We can't see your Delphi code. Perhaps that is wrong. [mcve]

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: So you could cut this down completely, remove all the parameters, remove all the commented out code, and just have a function with a single line `Erosion erosion = new Erosion();`

Comment: I can't provide more data about the exception. I don;t think Delphi can handle it. Doesn't the error come from the fact that I use Aforge in an unamanaged function that is exported?

Comment: Hefferman  Yes. I made tests and it shows that all Aforge functions generate errors

Comment: For future reference, such questions are far clearer if all extraneous aspects are removed.

Comment: I believe this problem is a very important one. There aren't many docs about importing unmanaged code or about generating it in C#:some nugget packages genrate errors on visual studio and are hard to install. Why close this question?

Comment: I edited the code to make it minimal. This matters. I presume that you still see the same issue with this code.

Comment: So you're more interested in the minimal version of code-you deleted only three lines- but in the problem itself.

Comment: Do you want help or not? I know what I am doing. Making examples as minimal as possible avoids distraction.

Comment: Now, which of the AForge names spaces do I need to use?

Comment: in C# I only used  AForge.Imaging.Filters but I think it has some dependicies. Overall I downloaded Aforge.Math,Imaging and the base Aforge packet 2.2.5

Comment: Isn't there a problem if I use Aforge functions which are managed in an exported,unmanaged function?

Comment: Right, I've added an answer.

Comment: As regards the question, I hope that you can see that it has been improved by removing as much code as possible. What is still lacking are the using statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be related to the location of the AForge DLLs. If you place those, and your class library DLL, in the same directory as your Delphi executable then the error disappears.

Perhaps there is some other way to tell AForge where to locate its DLLs. I will leave that as an exercise for the reader to investigate.

Comment: aren't the dlls statically added to the final dll?

Comment: No they are not.

Comment: It worked. Yes I was using a different path for the dll. I was still thinking in C++. I though other dlls were statically linked